# Is tension same in a chain with uniform mass distribution?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I have been troubled by this question for a long time. Let's say that I have a chain with mass 'M' and length 'L', now I know that if the mass wasn't distributed uniformly, then the tension would have been different at different lengths, however, **if the mass is uniformly distributed, then will this **chain have same tension at same distributions of mass**?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a chain of length $L$ and mass $M$ hanging under it's own weight. Suppose $x$ locates a point where I cut into the chain and examine the tension, $T(x)$:

[image]

You tell me that the mass distribution is homogenous. Therefore, the mass density per unit length $\rho$ is $\rho = \frac{M}{L}$ everywhere along the chain. The weight of chain hanging when I cut into it at $x$ is then $\rho g (L-x) = \frac{M}{L} g (L-x)$.

The force of the weight is balanced by the tension in equilibrium:

$T(x) = \frac{M}{L} g (L-x)$,

and therefore the tension varies from a value of $Mg$ at the support to $0$ at the free end.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Nice PG , and now I need more characters